# Citrus Framework - SFTP Server

Tags: citrus-framework

Is possible to make the sftp server to stay running long enough that I can use a command line sftp client to log in to do some troubleshooting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think your question could benefit from rewording.  I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a sleep action (https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/2.8.0/html/index.html#actions-sleep) to the test so you can do some manual troubleshooting while the test is waiting.